# virtual Host not being configured

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

I have cofigured httpd-vhosts.conf as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@repos
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Naveed-Laptop\repos\ustainable"
    ServerName   ustainable
    ErrorLog    "logs/ustainable-error.log"
    CustomLog   "logs/ustainable-acess.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Configured my hosts file 
    127.0.0.1   ustainable

but when i go to google chrome search and search for
        [http://ustainable]

it says

```
    Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ustainable
    Suggestions:
    Search on Google:
```

Comment: Please Provide some more description to get maximum help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was creating issue due to hotspot sheild and ErrorLog, CustomLog; i am using xampp 1.8

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName xampp.local
ServerAlias www.xampp.local
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\domain\html"
ServerName domain.local.com
ServerAlias www.domain.local.com
```

after adding it at the end of your httpd-vhosts.conf file restart your xampp and also add following lines to your hosts file available at C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1    domain.local.com
127.0.0.1      xampp.local
```

it will work for xampp 1.8 for remaining xampp versions hope so